# FTL Length contraction?

Tags: special-relativity, observers, faster-than-light

I found this interesting question in a textbook about special relativity:

> A length-contracted object has length $L=\frac{L_0}{\gamma}$. Joe differentiates this with respect to time and finds
> $$\frac{\mathrm dL}{\mathrm dt}=-L_0 \gamma v \frac{\mathrm dv}{\mathrm dt}$$
> He reasons that there is no upper limit on the magnitude of $\frac{\mathrm dv}{\mathrm dt}$ and therefore if $v\neq 0$ the quantity $\frac{\mathrm dL}{\mathrm dt}$ can be arbitrarily large.
> This means that if an object accelerates away from an observer, its
> trailing edge can have $v>c$, which is supposed to be forbidden by
> relativity. OMG! Is Joe’s reasoning correct?

I suppose that the $t$ here is not the objects proper time but rather Joe's coordinate time. I can not really see the flaw in his reasoning so I hoped someone on here might have a better understanding of relativity than me and can see the problem.

Comment: You should consider what Joe sees, what Joe deduces, and what is really happening, and then tell us what you think about them all.

Comment: This is quite a nice homework question (I might steal it!) and therefore, I'm afraid, off topic.

Comment: If copyright is not an issue feel free to use it. Would you like me to post the name of the book and the author?

Answer (score 1):

Well, the biggest flaw is that they are using a formula outside of the situation for which it was derived. The length contraction formula is derived for an inertially moving rod, not an accelerating rod.

With an inertially moving rod the length of the rod is constant in any inertial frame. So timing is not critical. With an accelerating rod the length is not constant so the question of timing becomes critical. It is not clear that the formula is applicable in that situation.